# Map email from one domain to another?

Tags: web-hosting

I have a client who purchased the .com, .net, and .org versions of his desired domain in order to capture visitors regardless of which tld the visitor enters.

I have no trouble re-directing actual web traffic to the desired "primary" domain (.com), but the client also wants to ensure that email sent to one domain is directed to the appropriate user at the primary domain.

For example, email addressed to user1@example.**net** would automatically redirect to user1@example.**com**, and emails to user2@example.**org** would similarly be redirected to user2@example.**com**.

The hosting company I'm using says that I'll need to create email forwards for each user on each secondary domain back to the actual mail account on the primary domain, but that seems kind of silly for what, to me, isn't a strange use-case. I guess it seems silly to me because on a previous host I was able to forward *@example.net to *@example.com as a single rule that worked for all mail addressed to the domain. Without this ability, even for only 10 users, that means I have to create 10  mailboxes (as expected), and 20 forwarding aliases (unexpected).

Does anyone else have any advice for these kinds of scenarios? Any hosting companies that are known to support such a setup?

Comment: Why would you say the host's advice is silly? Sounds correct to me.

Comment: This depends on what rights you have in regards to creating rules... For example, can you create forwarders based upon regex or wild cards? However, as a suggestion, consider a different approach. If you do this, it means these forwarders will never die and nor will those accounts. Instead, have auto replies with a typical "please update your records and use name@newDomain.com" to ensure these old accounts will 'die'

Comment: You may be better using a VPS for situations like this as well as that will give you control over the SMTP server you install.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dave. I don't think I have ability to use regex, but I hadn't thought to use an auto-responder to request the address be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use dreamhost.com as a mail host.  I don't wholeheartedly endorse them.  They mail service is slower than I would like and it has occasional downtime.  They do however support the feature that you are looking for.  They call it "email mirroring."

I have also used [RackSpace email](https://www.rackspace.com/email-hosting/webmail/features) which is more expensive but with much better reliability.   They also have the feature and call it "Domain aliases".